# Is it possible to turn on field debug drawing for SpriteKit in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

Is it possible to turn on field dubug drawing for SpriteKit in Xcode? I mean something like a picture below (it is from WWDC2014, session 608).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your view controller

Swift:

```
skView.showsFields = true
```

ObjC:

```
skView.showsFields = YES;
```